# Wrap GtkComboBox column-wise instead of row-wise

Tags: c, gtk3

I'm having trouble to wrap a GTKComboBox with a large number of alphabetically sorted entries column-wise instead of row-wise.

Please have a look at the following minimal working example and the attached screenshot to get an idea of what I'm trying to achieve. The focal point of my code is the function `gtk_combo_box_set_wrap_width` which wraps the GtkComboBox as table (see [GTK3 API reference](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.22/GtkComboBox.html#gtk-combo-box-set-wrap-width)).

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *combobox;

    gtk_init(&argc,&argv);

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window), 10 );
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 100, 50);

    combobox = gtk_combo_box_text_new();
    gtk_combo_box_text_append(GTK_COMBO_BOX_TEXT(combobox), NULL, "A" );
    gtk_combo_box_text_append(GTK_COMBO_BOX_TEXT(combobox), NULL, "B" );
    gtk_combo_box_text_append(GTK_COMBO_BOX_TEXT(combobox), NULL, "C" );
    gtk_combo_box_text_append(GTK_COMBO_BOX_TEXT(combobox), NULL, "D" );

    gtk_combo_box_set_wrap_width (GTK_COMBO_BOX(combobox), 2);

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), combobox);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();

    return(0);
}
```

This gives me the following output:

[image: Row-wise wrap]

As you can see, the entries get wrapped row-wise, i.e. are read from left to right.

Is there a convenient way to wrap the elements column-wise **without re-sorting them accordingly**?

[image: Column-wise wrap]

Comment: Use a GtkComboBox with a ListStore model, and then manipulate the order using `gtk_list_store_reorder()`; however, you must then maintain the sort order yourself (that is, add the entries to the list store in sorted order), and not use the GtkTreeSortable interface.